# Xamarin Android - How To Render HTML Table on Bitmap

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap, android-viewpager

I have been trying to render HTML with tables on a Bitmap but till now got no success.

I have tried to load HTML in a WebView and then using view.Draw or CapturePicture() to get a screenshot but everytime I get a blank screenshot because OnPageFinished() is executing later.

My Application is like

Main Activity -> ViewPager Activity -> Adapter Populates with imageCreationClass.cs which uses following code to capture picture

ViewPager Activity Class

```
public class TreeCatalog
{
    static TreePage[] treeBuiltInCatalog = {
        new TreePage {
            imageId = Resource.Drawable.larch,
            caption = "Introduction",
            bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(tempPath + "1.jpg")
        },

        new TreePage {
            imageId = Resource.Drawable.maple,
            caption = "Highlights",
            bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(tempPath + "2.jpg")
        },

         new TreePage {
            imageId = Resource.Drawable.maple,
            caption = "Illustration",
            bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(tempPath + "3.jpg")
         },             
    };      

    private TreePage[] treePages;
    public TreeCatalog() { treePages = treeBuiltInCatalog; }
    public TreePage this[int i] { get { return treePages[i]; } }
    public int NumTrees { get { return treePages.Length; } }
}
```

imageCreationClass.cs

```
public static void preparePageThree()
    {
        WebView web = new WebView(logic.context);                        
        web.Layout(0, 0, 800, 800);
        web.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        web.LoadData(HtmlSource, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }


public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            //Picture picture = view.CapturePicture();

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.InMutable = true;

            Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.Argb8888;
            bmp = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(200, 200, conf);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
            //canvas.DrawColor(Color.Beige);
            view.Draw(canvas);
            //canvas.DrawPicture(picture);

            if(File.Exists(tempPath + "3.jpg"))
            {
                File.Delete(tempPath + "3.jpg");
            }

            using (var os = new System.IO.FileStream(logic.tempPath + "3.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                bmp.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 95, os);
            }                
        }

        public override void OnReceivedError(WebView view, ClientError errorCode, string description, string failingUrl)
        {
            base.OnReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    }
```

Please guide If there are better ways we can render HTML directly on image (Bitmap).

Comment: Could you please post the codes of your `ViewPager` Adapter? If you use Fragment for Adapter,please also post the codes of your Fragment.

Comment: its taken from this example https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/TreePager

I am simply providing my images for pager tabs

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to load HTML in a WebView and then using view.Draw or CapturePicture() to get a screenshot but everytime I get a blank screenshot because OnPageFinished() is executing later.

WebView loads html asynchronously, and the loading time is much depends on the network condition. So, it's not what you can control.

My suggestion is, put a loading to your current activity, and during the loading time prepare all the bitmaps with webview. After that, initialize your `ViewPager` adapter with prepared bitmaps.